# Cuando en Visual Studio Code se muestran métodos tachados, ¿qué significa?

Tags: jquery, vscode

Cuando en VSC se muestra el método de esta manera, ¿qué significa? ¿Que ya no está disponible?

[image: cuando en vsc se muestra el metodo de esta manera. que significa ? que ya no esta disponible ? quien me ayuda por favor]

Comment: [Porque está obsoleto](https://github.com/jquery/jquery-migrate/blob/main/warnings.md#jqmigrate-jqueryfnclick-event-shorthand-is-deprecated). En su lugar, utiliza `.on("click", fn)`

Answer (score 3):

Cuando una librería marca una funcionalidad como "obsoleta" o desaconseja su uso (por ejemplo, aparece el término `@deprecated` en la documentación, [como en este caso](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/f7ec78508c6797e42f87a4390735bc2c650a1bfd/types/jquery/JQuery.d.ts#L1875)), los IDE detectan esta anotación y marcan la función con un texto tachado.
esto significa que esa funcionalidad existe pero no se recomienda su uso.

Comment: çGracias lo supuse :D